# Cruisecontrol Group Projects

Tags: projects, cruisecontrol

Is it possible to group projects in CruiseControl?

(I know it is possible to group them using the same prefixes... but is it possible to really group them?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a tag under "project":

```
<project ...>
  <category>Category 1</category>
  ...
</project>
```

and according to CruiseControl documentation: "A general category for this project. This is used by the dashboard to provide groupings to the project. Categories do not span servers."

Comment: Apparently only to be used in CruiseControl.NET

Comment: Ooops, sorry, didn't realize you are using the original CruiseControl.